# SFINAE Member Function Test Explanation

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

I am using the following TypeTrait struct to detect whether a given has a given method (with specific args) defined.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
struct HasSomeMethod
{
    //Simulates a call to a Type with SomeMethod(ArgType&) defined
    template<typename Type, typename ArgType>
    static auto CallMemberMethod(Type& type, ArgType& arg) -> decltype(type.SomeMethod(arg));

    //Will be picked if the above call can succeed
    template<typename Type, typename ArgType>
    static auto Test() -> decltype(CallMemberMethod(std::declval<Type&>(), std::declval<ArgType&>()), std::true_type());

    //Fallback...the Serialize() call failed
    template<typename, typename>
    static std::false_type Test(...);

    //Result of the test
    static const bool value { std::is_same<decltype(Test<T, A>()), std::true_type>::value };
};
```

I have a general idea of how this works. What I don't understand is why the methods need to be templated in addition to the struct itself.

As in:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
struct HasSomeMethod
{
    static auto CallMemberMethod(T& type, A& arg) -> decltype(type.SomeMethod(arg));

    static auto Test() -> decltype(CallMemberMethod(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<A&>()), std::true_type());

    static std::false_type Test(...);

    static const bool value { std::is_same<decltype(Test()), std::true_type>::value };
};
```

This fails with a compiler error:  `ambiguous call to overloaded function`

What prevents re-using the template typenames that the struct is already provided for the methods as well?

Comment: Substitution Failure **in the immediate context, while doing template argument deduction** Is Not An Elephant. Other substitution failures (like when you are substituting into member function signatures while instantiating a class template) *are* Elephants.

Comment: Also, [your first version is wrong, too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05e43dd7efc778dd).

Comment: Overloading `Test()` with `Test(...)` makes calling `Test()` ambiguous in clang and gcc. If you're using msvc, it works on that, however.

Comment: @JamesRoot MSVC doesn't even have official expression SFINAE support until a week ago...

Comment: @T.C. That can't be right. I've had it work (mostly) successfully for like, forever. Or I'm having a stroke right now.

Comment: @JamesRoot http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1.aspx Previous versions are in the "no *official* support, may works in some cases and explode in others" category. Note the "No" in the Expression SFINAE line in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx

Comment: @ James Root Any ideas about the fix would be to get it to compile and work with clang and gcc, while maintaining compatibility with VS2015 as well?